# How to get class of div using jquery onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this sort of html:

```
<div style="animation-duration: 1.5s; opacity: 1;" id="wrapper" class="clearfix website outerDiv" data-url="/websites/<%= @website.id %>">
    <section id="slider" class="slider-parallax innerDiv" style="background: transparent url(<%= @website.background_image.present? ? @website.background_image : (image_path current_user.website.theme.image_name) %>) no-repeat scroll 0% 0% / cover ; height: 600px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);" data-height-lg="600" data-height-md="500" data-height-sm="400" data-height-xs="300" data-height-xxs="250">
        <div class="contentDiv" id="clearfix">
            <div style="margin-top: 5px; width: 170px; height: 170px;" id="imageEditor" class="imageEditor" data-attr="logo" id="website-logo">
                mycontent
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; width: 100%; margin-top: -81px; opacity: 1.77778;" class="website-title vertical-middle dark center">
                <div class="heading-block nobottommargin center">
                    <div contenteditable="true" class="textEditor" data-attr="heading" id="website-title">
                        mycontent
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden-xs textEditor" contenteditable="true" data-attr="description" id="website-desc">mycontent</div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="button button-border button-light button-rounded button-reveal tright button-large topmargin hidden-xs"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i><span>Start Tour</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Now, here I want to capture div class for the div I will click on.

the function I am trying is but it is not working as expected. It keep giving only first div class:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.outerDiv').click(function () {
        alert($(this).attr('class'));
    });
});
```

Comment: `this.classname` is a good alternative.

Comment: If I uses this, it says `undefined`. Tried number of things so far.

Comment: because it has to be `.className`

Comment: tried this too. No luck. @Andreas

Comment: What is happening?? are you not getting the classes in alert? can you please give an example of output u wamt?

Comment: My desired output would be, if I click on any of the div from html it simply returns me its class right now it is only returning first class not the inner ones where I click. So, its not working.

Comment: @LearningROR For that look my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is about the selector. And opening the selector you have to stop the propagation to not have all parents firing the same event.

Try this:

```
<div style="animation-duration: 1.5s; opacity: 1;" id="wrapper" class="clearfix website outerDiv" data-url="/websites/<%= @website.id %>">
    <section id="slider" class="slider-parallax innerDiv" style="background: transparent url(<%= @website.background_image.present? ? @website.background_image : (image_path current_user.website.theme.image_name) %>) no-repeat scroll 0% 0% / cover ; height: 600px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);" data-height-lg="600" data-height-md="500" data-height-sm="400" data-height-xs="300" data-height-xxs="250">
        <div class="contentDiv" id="clearfix">
            <div style="margin-top: 5px; width: 170px; height: 170px;" id="imageEditor" class="imageEditor" data-attr="logo" id="website-logo">
                mycontent
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; width: 100%; margin-top: -81px; opacity: 1.77778;" class="website-title vertical-middle dark center">
                <div class="heading-block nobottommargin center">
                    <div contenteditable="true" class="textEditor" data-attr="heading" id="website-title">
                        mycontent
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden-xs textEditor" contenteditable="true" data-attr="description" id="website-desc">mycontent</div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="button button-border button-light button-rounded button-reveal tright button-large topmargin hidden-xs"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i><span>Start Tour</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.outerDiv, .outerDiv div').click(function (e) {
        alert($(this).attr('class'));
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is the meaning of: `$('.outerDiv, .outerDiv div').click(function (e) {` ? I want to know about `outerDiv, .outerDiv div`

Comment: Please explain your JS code also. That will help me understand the problem and knowledge. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The following can get the class name of the exact element on which the click happened.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.outerDiv').click(function (e) {
        alert(e.target.className);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="animation-duration: 1.5s; opacity: 1;" id="wrapper" class="clearfix website outerDiv" data-url="/websites/<%= @website.id %>">
    <section id="slider" class="slider-parallax innerDiv" style="background: transparent url(<%= @website.background_image.present? ? @website.background_image : (image_path current_user.website.theme.image_name) %>) no-repeat scroll 0% 0% / cover ; height: 600px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);" data-height-lg="600" data-height-md="500" data-height-sm="400" data-height-xs="300" data-height-xxs="250">
        <div class="contentDiv" id="clearfix">
            <div style="margin-top: 5px; width: 170px; height: 170px;" id="imageEditor" class="imageEditor" data-attr="logo" id="website-logo">
                mycontent
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; width: 100%; margin-top: -81px; opacity: 1.77778;" class="website-title vertical-middle dark center">
                <div class="heading-block nobottommargin center">
                    <div contenteditable="true" class="textEditor" data-attr="heading" id="website-title">
                        mycontent
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden-xs textEditor" contenteditable="true" data-attr="description" id="website-desc">mycontent</div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="button button-border button-light button-rounded button-reveal tright button-large topmargin hidden-xs"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i><span>Start Tour</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Strangely your code returns me empty alert. I am surprised well.

Comment: @LearningROR empty alerts are coming when the click target is an element which doesn't have a class name.

Comment: why `$('.outerDiv, .outerDiv div').click(function (e) {` works well with accepted answer but not with yours? what does this mean? can you explain.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.outerDiv ').click(function (e) {
        console.log(e.target.className);
    });
});
```

Would work like a charm, plus its better that you use console.log rather than alert to view things

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.outerDiv').click(function () {    
      var className = $(this).attr('class');
      alert(className);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It will alert the class of the div on which the event has been attached to. You will need to bind the events for all the divs you need the class for. And in case you need the class for the parent div, just refer it within the bound function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a specific class present or not then you can use `".hasClass('className')"`

If you want all the classes on the div

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.outerDiv').click(function () {    
      var className = this.className;
      alert(className);
    });
});
```

This is a native JS method, not jquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that, on clicking of any div from your page will alert class name for that div, than you Need to bind [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event on all of div present in your page. 
Also prevent your click event to propagate to parent div, so that it will show only current div click class name.

Try this code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('div').on('click', function(e) {
       alert($(this).attr('class'));
       e.stopPropagation();
   });
});
```

Here is [Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yrsazat2/1/)

Comment: Its not working for section tag. sorry. its not returning its content as it has background image in it.

Comment: So its fulfilling my requirement sorry.

Comment: It will return the class name of your div. even though it is inside section tag..

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   $('div').on('click', function(e) {
       console.log(e.target.className);
       e.stopPropagation();
   });
});
```

Comment: Its not working for section tag. sorry. its not returning its content as it has background.